# Dividing a large module into multiple files

Tags: perl

Apologies, It looks like my original question was not able to correctly explain what I am doing and what I want to achieve. Here is an updated question.

This may be the easiest question, but I can't find an answer anywhere.

I have a large Perl module (say ABC.pm) which keeps on growing day by day as we add new functions. Most of these functions (almost 90%) send requests and process responses. Here is some code for one such request.

```
sub UserDeleteRequest
{
    my ($self, $inputParam) = @_;
    my $config = $self->getConfig();
    return $self->_doRequest (REQUEST => 'UserDeleteRequest',
                              PARAM => $inputParam));
}
```

Similar to this, other functions are written and it keeps on growing as we add new requests.

Having a large file is becoming difficult to maintain. So, I am looking for some best practices to make this easier. One idea that I thought of was to split this large module into multiple files (how??)

Comment: What kind of requests are we talking about? SOAP? Database? Something else? If there are many requests of different kinds that need to be handled differently but are all sent and received in the same way then adding handler functions together with @Ilion's answer might be a good idea.

Comment: -1 too vague to give useful answers. Show some real code, then one can make real recommendations.

Comment: I'm skeptical that they have no commonalities. If they don't then they definitely shouldn't be in the same file. If they do then you can abstract those commonalities out and create proper classes and handler functions, as @simbabque suggests.

Comment: @daxim - updated my question. Hope this look good.

Comment: Are you suggesting you've filled this file with a large group of functions where the only thing different is the value assigned to REQUEST?

Comment: Yes this file is filled with large group of such functions. The difference is the value assigned in REQUEST and PARAM. Sometimes caller of the function does not provide $inputParam then we have to find the default one and pass it to _doRequest subroutine.

Comment: But the value assigned by the function to PARAM is not different, if what you're saying is true because it is always $inputParam. All you've done is bloat your code by not calling the _doRequest method directly. Either these functions are somehow more complex and dividing each call type into its own package makes sense, or you're causing yourself far too much work.

Comment: @Ilion is right. In that case my answer doesn't even make sense. You could just build a wrapper that knows about all the different requests, maybe from a config hash. The wrapper function would just have to do the proper preps for each different request and then call it. Would be a lot shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the subs are really very similar, why not generalize into ONE sub?

```
my %validRequests = map {($_ => 1)} qq(UserDeleteRequest);

sub SendRequest {
    my ($self, $request, $inputParam) = @_;
    my $config = $self->getConfig();
    return undef unless $validReqiests{$request}; # If want to verify
    # 
    $inputParam = getInputParamDefault($request) unless $inputParam; 
    return $self->_doRequest (REQUEST => $inputParam,
                              PARAM => $inputParam));
}
```

If there are other logical differences between some types of subs, you can address them by either doing proper OO with inheritance, as Ilion's answer notes; or you can do the simpler approach of having a per-request-type hashes of helper sub references in simpler cases.

I added a special `getInputParamDefault()` call get to address your comment "Sometimes caller of the function does not provide $inputParam then we have to find the default one and pass it to _doRequest subroutine."

---

**UPDATE**: If you MUST keep the original sub names due to legacy code calling them that you can't refactor, you can auto-generate them (either using AUTOLOAD or by adding to namespace by hand):

```
# Code not tested.
my %requestSubNames = ("UserDeleteRequest" => "UserDeleteRequest");
foreach my $requestType (sort keys %requestSubNames) {
    no strict 'refs';
    my $subName = __PACKAGE__ . "::$requestSubNames{$requestType}";
    *{$subname} = sub { return $_[0]->SendRequest($requestType, $_[1]); };
        # Note - this may need to be closure-tweaked, it's 5am and I'm a bit asleep
    # Add to EXPORT/EXPORT_OK if needed
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful. But the external application directly call the function $client->UserDeleteRequest().

Comment: @rpg - you can inject the functions into your package namespace (either using AUTOLOAD which I don't much like, or doing it youself)

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you should make an abstract class which you can have other classes inherit from and override. To go with your rather vague example, your module might look like:

```
use strict;
package Foo;

sub new {

    my $class = ref(shift) || shift;
    my $self = {};
    bless( $self, $class );

    return $self;

}

sub processFooRequest {
    ...
}

sub processFooResponse {
    ...
}
```

You might then have a child class Foo::Web and it might look something like this:

```
use strict;
package Foo::Web;
use base "Foo";

sub processFooWebRequest {
    ...
}

sub processFooWebResponse {
    ...
}
```

In this case I didn't bother with a new constructor because it inherits from Foo. I could leave the methods with the same names and they would simply override - and really that's probably what I should do - keep the names the same but change the inner functionality. Any other methods defined in Foo would be inherited.

Really you should take a look at [perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html). Once you start to understand that, and its various links, you might want to look at [Moose](http://www.catalyzed.org/2009/06/a-gentle-introduction-to-moose.html).

Comment: @llion - Apologies for this vague example. using this example, I want to convey that all the functions does the same thing. My main worry about the number of main function. I will try to modify the pseudo code for better readability.

Comment: If all the functions do the same thing then why would you have multiple functions? I'm assuming you mean they all do very similar things. If that's the case you should be able to make use of inheritance as I described, making small changes to variables or functions as needed. Abstract as much as you can and then fill in with small overrides.

Answer (score 0):

How about the [AUTOLOAD](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Autoloading) feature? That would not be the most efficient way, but if they all look like the example and do not really do much processing, that would save you all those identical lines of code.

```
package test;
use strict; use warnings;
our $AUTOLOAD;

sub AUTOLOAD {
  my $self = $_[0];
  # we DONT shift it, since the whole @_ is needed 
  # for the goto &$AUTOLOAD at the end

  if ($AUTOLOAD =~ /.*::(.*)/) {
    my $requestType = $1;
    return undef if $requestType eq 'DESTROY';

    $AUTOLOAD = sub {
      my ($self, $inputParam) = @_;
      my $config = $self->getConfig(); # Why do we need this?
      return $self->_doRequest (REQUEST => $requestType,
                                PARAM => $inputParam);
    };
    # This is NOT a 'goto LABEL' call. This goto calls the function we
    # just have created and passes the whole @_ as arguments to it.
    # See 'http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/goto.html' for details.
    goto &$AUTOLOAD;
  }
}

sub getConfig { return 1; }
sub _doRequest { my ($self, %foo) = @_; return $foo{REQUEST}; }
sub new { return bless {}, $_[0]; }

package main;
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my $test = test->new;
print Dumper $test->foobar('nice param');
```

Basically the AUTOLOAD functionality creates methods that do not exist for you. In our case, it creates an anonymous sub that makes the request for a request type `foobar` and hands the param `'nice param'` to it.

You could also go on saying

```
$test->getMilk('goat');
$test->isThereBeerLeftInTheFridge({ temp => 'cold', size => 'large'})
```

or whatever other requests there are.

Maybe this is a starting point. It's not the fastest solution if all the requests are done constantly. It will, however, only create each method once and use it afterwards if it is called again.

Comment: I would not want to be the dev a few years from now who had to troubleshoot the project this was used on.

Comment: I do like DVK's solution better. But hey, TIMTOWTDI, right? ;-) So seriously: what upsets you about it? Please give me constructive feedback, it's apreciated.

Comment: On the surface nothing. At a glance the code all looks fine and nice. But when you come into the project a couple years down the road from this being implemented, the original programmer has moved on, and you're trying to track down some weird function that's failing it's going to lead to some confusion and frustration. Especially if it further up an inheritance tree. (On the other hand, you could probably write it in fewer lines....)

Comment: I see your point. This might easily turn into a discussion of principles. Let's better not go down that road. I just believe that sometimes it's better to write more documentation and fewer, yet faster/better/whatever code than to write loads of verbose code that performs weaker. I don't think this answer is the best solution, it is just the first that came to my mind.